# How to Create a structure (e.g. a list) from a for loop output?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, data-structures

```
u = range(1,30,1)
for s in u:
    print(s**-1*500)
```

I need assistance with creating a list or an array from the results of the For loop.

Comment: Note that the default value of `step`, the third argument of `range`, is `1`. So `range(1,30,1)` is the same as `range(1,30)`. Also note that the resulting list will have 29 elements, not 30, because it goes from `1` included to `30` excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension.

```
u = [s**-1*500 for s in range(1,30)]
```

Notes:
`range` default step is `1` so it could be skipped here.
List comprehensions are generally faster than appending elements to list in `for` loop. It's also more pythonic way of doing such tasks.

Comment: Please note that `s**-1*500` is very different from `s**(-1*500)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create an empty list
item_list = []
for s in u:
    # Append each item to list.
    item_list.append(s**-1*500)
```

Comment: Please **never** call a variable `list` in python. This name is already used for the builtin class `list`, which is super important. Don't overshadow it.

Comment: It's slower than list comprahension

Comment: @Stef you're right. I edited the code. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ways to do it.

**For loop**

```
u = range(1,30,1)
values = []
for s in u:
    values.append(s**-1*500)
```

**List Comprehension**

```
values = [s**-1*500 for s in range(1,30,1)]
```

Use whichever suits your need

Comment: Please note that `s**-1*500` is very different from `s**(-1*500)`.

Comment: Thanks. Good pick. I have fixed it.

Comment: Also please **never** call a variable `list` in python. This name is already used for the builtin class `list`, which is super important. Don't overshadow it.

Comment: The two propositions are also inconsistent - in the first one, `u` is the range, while in the second, `u` is the list of results.